# Configuring custom RelayState in xml configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-saml2

I want to set the `RelayState` parameter so that I can pass a **redirectUrl** received at runtime from a different request. This was possible in the SAML extension library by overriding the `getProfileOptions()` method of the `SAMLEntryPoint` class. However, it is not possible to do the same in Spring Security even with the following XML configuration:

```
<http>
       <saml2-login relying-party-registration-repository-ref="xxxxx">
</http>
```

I cannot find a sample application that showcases how to create a `relying-party-registration-repository` bean where I can pass the `relying-party-registrations` to its constructor. The `relying-party-registrations` should allow `alias` to be used as a reference in some other place.